# Webpack Externals Configuration for a Local Library

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I want to setup my Webpack config (v4+) to exclude an import that is referencing a local library.  In my app, I import this library like so:

**/src/index.js**

```javascript
import foo from '../foo/foo'

console.log(foo);
```

**/foo/foo.js**

```javascript
export default foo = "bar";
```

**webpack.config.js**

```javascript
const path = require('path')
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      filename: 'main.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    externals: {
      "foo": path.resolve(__dirname, "./foo/foo"),
    }
  };
```

However, this library is actually already referenced globally in the site where I'm deploying my application. So I do not want this library bundled with my application (I still need to import it so that I can transpile my typescript without errors and use intellisense).

I found out that I can easily exclude a library from being bundled by utilizing the externals property like so:

```javascript
module.exports = {
  externals: {
    "jquery": "jQuery"
  }
}
```

I've been unsuccessful at doing the same with the library that I'm importing.  How would I go about doing this? I've tried the following and the library is still included in my bundle:

I have been researching documentation and can only seem to find examples related to node modules and nothing specific to my requirements.

Please let me know if you need any additional details. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have type declarations for that specific library?

Comment: Make sure you import from `Foo` and not from the complete path to `Foo`. i.e. `import {something} from 'Foo';`

Comment: @dustin see my answer below

Comment: @PAckerman I don't have a type declarations for that library.  It's mainly just a ts file that's exporting a class like export class Foo {}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for WebPack to treat your import as *external*, your import declaration must be using the same alias you defined in the WebPack `extenals` configuration, and NOT a relative path:

```
import Foo from 'foo';
```

WebPack:

```
module.exports = {
  externals: {
    "foo": path.resolve(__dirname, "./path/to/foo")
  }
}
```

Comment: Revised code in original question.  Does that change your answer at all?

Comment: Not really (only in casing...). You are importing using a relative path, instead of using the `foo` alias. That's why it isn't working for you.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know that I could just use an alias in stead of relative path after configuring webpack.

Comment: @Dustin glad I could help!

Comment: So I originally thought that this was working for me, but it was actually excluding the file since there was an error in the bundle. 

ERROR in bundle.js from Terser
Unexpected token: punc (:)

When I loaded it up in the browser, I was seeing that the external was referencing my local file system (e.g., "C:\path\to\foo"). I'm not sure whether or not that this error caused the file to not be included in the bundle, or that is another error not related to this question.

Comment: If this is correct, and I cannot use the relative path when doing my import statement, then I cannot do unit testing.. as jest will work on the js files, not the webpack'ed version. I am stuck as to how to exclude a local file from the bundle...